# Phpmyadmin y Java

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, servidor

Estoy tratando de hacer un servidor de BDD, para poder conectarme con java (ide:netbeas), la duda es como va la clase conexion, ya que pienso que es aqui mi problema para acceder a la base de datos que cree en phpmyadmin.
Obvio cuento con ip publica...
Debo de abrir puertos?
Asi tengo mi clase conexion:

```
public void init(){
   try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://miippublica:puertoconelqueaccedoaphpmyadmin/prueba","user", "password");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el servidor lo hostea usted y quiere "abrirlo a internet" si, va a tener que abrir puertos, respecto a lo que ha puesto en su código, no estoy del todo seguro si es correcto. Para comprobarlo, en vez de usar su ip publica (asumiendo que este servidor que usted hostea es en local, si no, use la ip pública), use localhost:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:puerto/prueba","user", "password");
```

Si no funciona así, el problema está en su ip pública, o no está bien configurada, o el puerto no está abierto (aunque repito que si el server es en localhost no es necesario abrirlo para poder testearlo en local).

En la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) de la librería jdbc, la sintaxis que usan para conectarse es diferente a la que usted tiene, por lo que también podría probar el siguiente código:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/prueba?" +
                               "user=user&password=pass");
```

Sustituyendo los valores de `user` y `pass` por los suyos.